Error: pg_config executable not found in a dockerfile
I'm getting an issue with psycopg2 when I build the image on Debian machine.
I have a dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12-slim
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT [ "streamlit","run","main.py","--server.port=8501", "--server.address=0.0.0.0"]

to generate requirements.txt i run pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt
and a part of the requirements.txt:
ply==3.11
prometheus_client==0.20.0
prompt_toolkit==3.0.47
protobuf==4.25.3
psutil==6.0.0
psycopg2==2.9.9
pure_eval==0.2.3
pyarrow==16.1.0
pycparser==2.22
pydeck==0.8.0
Pygments==2.18.0

when I build the image I got this error :
 Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
18.19   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
18.19
18.19   × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
18.19   │ exit code: 1
18.19   ╰─> [21 lines of output]
18.19       running egg_info
18.19       writing psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
18.19       writing dependency_links to psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
18.19       writing top-level names to psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
18.19
18.19       Error: pg_config executable not found.
18.19
18.19       pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
18.19       containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
18.19       option:
18.19
18.19           python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
18.19
18.19       or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
18.19
18.19       If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
18.19       'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
18.19
18.19       For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
18.19       <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
18.19
18.19       [end of output]
18.19
18.19   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
18.30 error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Do you have any idea please why I'm getting this error  ?
thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%22Error%3A+pg_config+executable+not+found%22
